# Can a raw pointer be passed to a template function expecting an iterator?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

Can raw pointers be passed to template functions expecting iterators? Am I right in thinking that an iterator is just a class which overrides the pointer-related operators (e.g. *, ++, etc.), or do iterators expose any additional interface that pointers do not? To put it another way, do pointers "look like" iterators?

Example:

I want to use `boost::algorithm::knuth_morris_pratt_search` ([documentation here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0_beta1/libs/algorithm/doc/html/the_boost_algorithm_library/Searching/KnuthMorrisPratt.html)).

My corpus (string to be searched) and pattern (string being looked for) are simply bytes in memory - I have a pointer containing the start address, and the length in bytes. For the sake of the argument, let's say it's a c-style string.

According to the documentation, the `knuth_morris_pratt_search` function requires me to pass in start and end iterators for both the corpus and the pattern.

**Function I wish to use:**

```
template <typename patIter, typename corpusIter>
corpusIter knuth_morris_pratt_search (
        corpusIter corpus_first, corpusIter corpus_last,
        patIter pat_first, patIter pat_last );
```

**Can I do this?**

```
// Assume these are initialized:
char* c;
int cLength;
char* p;
int pLength;

char* result = knuth_morris_pratt_search<char*, char*>
   (c, c + cLength, p, p + pLength);
```

Comment: seems fine,, did you give it a try?

Comment: @user814628 Not yet. I could have just tried it, but that wouldn't prove it works in the general sense, only that it works for my test. I might later try to do the same thing in a scenario where it would fail, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking that an iterator is just a class which overrides the pointer-related operators (e.g. *, ++, etc.),

You are correct; pointers to data stored in arrays match the requirements for *random access iterators*, i.e. the most "complete" iterator type, so you can use them in substantially any standard library algorithm.

I don't have the standard at hand for the full reference about random access iterators, but see e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/); also, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) is a nice diagram with the various "types" of iterators.